# Trying to insert values into a MYSQL table using PHP - No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having problems with my PHP code. I'm trying to insert data into 6 fields based off user input, and I need to make sure the database/table already exists before adding it. I've called a query ("CREATE DATABASE 'Students' IF NOT EXISTS") and select_db('Students') but it still returns an error saying that the database doesn't exist. Code is below:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
$dbcheck = 'CREATE DATABASE `Students` IF NOT EXISTS';
$link->query($dbcheck);
$link->select_db("Students");
$students = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Students` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`lname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`address` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`phone` int(30) unsigned NOT NULL default '',
`dateofbirth` int(30) unsigned NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY_KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
$link->query($students);
$FNAME = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['fname']);
$LNAME = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['lname']);
$ADDRESS = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['address']);
$EMAIL = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$PHONE = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['phone']);
$DATEOFBIRTH = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['dateofbirth']);

if ($link->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO Students (fname,lname,address,email,phone,dateofbirth)
VALUES ('$FNAME','$LNAME','$ADDRESS','$EMAIL','$PHONE','$DATEOFBIRTH')";

if ($link->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $link->error;
}

$link->close();
?>
```

Comment: You've to create database manually first.

Comment: No, but you need to use the right [CREATE DATABASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html) syntax. Hint - matches the `CREATE TABLE` syntax you used.

Comment: Checking for errors on every SQL query is a good idea too.

Comment: You should check for errors more often - how far does all that code succeed to work?

Comment: The database is now created, but I also get an error when trying to insert values, saying that the table Students.students does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Students`